# How to debug web project in MyEclipse using JBoss server?

Tags: java, debugging, jboss, remote-debugging, myeclipse

I am new to jboss and myeclipse.
I want to debug my web app using **jboss 4.0.4** 
I am using MyEclipse.

I gone through various links and found we need to uncomment following line in **run.bat** file

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y %JAVA_OPTS%
```

then after starting run.bat console shows

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
```

Then next how do I tell MyEclipse to attach to port 8787 and run my application in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a Remote Java Application in the Eclipse debug configurations:

- Open the debug configurations (select project, then open from menu run/debug configurations)
- Select `Remote Java Application` in the left tree and press "New" button
- On the right panel select your web app project and enter 8787 in the port field.

Here is a link to a [detailed description](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-remotejava_launch_config.htm) of this process.

When you start the remote debug configuration Eclipse will attach to the JBoss process. If successful the debug view will show the JBoss threads. There is also a disconnect icon in the toolbar/menu to stop remote debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Define a new server/runtime in MyEclipse, for your JBoss 4 installation. Deploy your project to the defined server and start it in debugging mode.

For more information, go to the [MyEclipse learning center](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/deploy/myeclipse-application-server-connectors/), also [here](https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/deploy/myeclipse-basic-application-server-tutorial/).

For earlier releases, check in the inbuilt help.